# Why does the magma_dgemm function not use tensor cores on the V100 GPU?

Tags: cuda, nvidia, blas, cublas, magma

I run MAGMA `testing_dgemm` code both on V100 and H100 GPU. With Nsight Systems, I found that on the V100 the code doesn't use tensor cores, but code on the H100 it does.

V100 result:

[image: Nisght Systems profiler screenshot]

H100 result:

[image: Nisght Systems profiler screenshot]

The tensor core has been used in Volta GPU according to NVIDIA web.

The NVIDIA [Inside Volta](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/inside-volta/) blog seems not to mention the FP64 TC performances.

Comment: See also [Double-Precision Tensor Cores Speed High-Performance Computing](https://blogs.nvidia.com/blog/2020/05/14/double-precision-tensor-cores/) on the developer blog about A100 tensor cores.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The v100 GPU doesn't have a FP64 (double precision) path in its TensorCore unit.

That path/capability was introduced in Ampere A100 3rd gen TensorCore.

So when performing FP64 arithmetic, V100 generally will not use TensorCore.

From [here](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/data-center/a100/):

> NVIDIA A100 ***introduces double precision Tensor Cores*** ...

(emphasis added)

Comment: wow...thx a lot!! this problem has troubled me for long time..

Comment: sorry here i have a follow up question.. I also test "testing_sgemm" code on v100. On the Nsight, it appears that no tensor core was used (the result is similar to the dgemm). But i find that NVidia claims that  "Tensor Cores accelerating FP32 matrix math deliver more than 120 TFLOPS of performance". So it seems v100 has a FP32 path in the tensor core unit?

Comment: @ingridli I think Volta Tensor cores are only for mixed precision, i.e. FP16 input. Using them here would result in different/worse results.

Comment: that seems make sense.. thx again. i will check nvidia's blog later.